# 70s(?) kids' short story: spaceship lands, crystal plants/animals, spacesuits slowly cut by glass and they all die

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Kids' Short Story: SciFi/Horror. A spaceship, illustrated like a classic 1950 pulp rocket resting on its bottom fins, lands on planet with glass and crystal plants and animals.  The beauty of the alien landscape turns to horror as they realized that the vegetation is cutting their space suits. Upon trying to return to the ship their space suits are slowly compromised by glass shards and they all(?) die.

Read in the mid 70’s from elementary school library. Large hardcover book (smaller than 8x11) with colour illustrations and other horror stories.

Comment: The -genre tags are only to be used on questions about the genre and not to classify works of fiction. Please don't add it again.

Comment: Q: Should the “horror” tag be removed as well?

Comment: It doesn’t make much sense but that one doesn’t have to be removed.

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/226025/short-story-with-explorers-or-tourists-on-a-planet-with-dangerous-but-attractiv?noredirect=1&lq=1 ?